# Graph API rate limits: do test apps have their own limit?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently developing a facebook App whose purpose is to

- For a given page, list the last X posts
- For each of said posts, list the last Y comments
- For each of said posts, list the last W reactions (e.g. likes)
- For the page as a whole, display the Z most active users considering the last X posts

The app is not yet published (And, since it'll only provide server to server communication, it might never be) and it currently has one admin and 4 test users.

I'm currently hitting rate limits for the [comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/comments) endpoint, whereas I've never got any alert for the [reactions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/reactions) endpoint.

The [rate limit documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting) says that some endpoints do not count for rate limiting, but it doesn't say which ones. So I assume that, in my case, only the comments API calls are eating my rate limit.

One approach I might consider to go over the rate limit is to create [test apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps) for my app. They do have their own app-id and app-secret, and *share the same app-scoped User ID namespace*, so user IDs will be consistent and I'll be able to use both Apps to display aggregate data.

What I don't know is **do test apps have their own rate limit?**, or do they "eat" part of the production app rate limit?

I want to avoid creating the logic to rotate the App credentials on each call only to discover the rate is still the same.

**Edit**: I created a test app and hardcoded some calls to use its credentials. However, said calls aren't shown in test app's dashboard. I believe this would mean that its calls are attributed to the main app anyway.

Comment: Those limits are in place for a reason - and when you hit them, that means you should make less requests, not try and cheat the system. Don’t try to circumvent them by using test apps.

Comment: Creating new apps (one per each Page I want to display stats for) isn't meant to cheat the system. It's just extra work that I want to avoid unless I really need to. Creating test apps is a middle ground that would spare me some logic.